# client side with unix socket in angular

Tags: angular, unix-socket

created server app with unix socket in golang

server app code:

```
package main
import (
  "fmt"
  "net"
  "net/http"
  "os"
)
func main() {
  sock := "/var/web.sock"
  err := os.Remove(sock)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Can not remove socket config file.")
  }
  unixListener, err := net.Listen("unix", sock)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Can not create unix socket listener,")
  }
  http.HandleFunc("/3dviewer/upload", uploadFile)
  http.Serve(unixListener, nil)
}
func uploadFile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   fmt.Printf("WORKING") 
}
```

need client side angular code to connect to server app. please some one can help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use reverse proxy such as Nginx to handle Angular HTTP/HTTPS call, and forward to the Unix Socket

In case of you use nginx, you can create a configuration at `/etc/nginx/site-available/your_configuration_file`

Then enable it by

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/your_configuration_file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

An example for the Nginx configuration file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server_domain_or_IP;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```